# Syntax error when update root password

Tags: mysql-8.0, password-recovery, root

I forgot MySQL root password so I am trying to change it by starting it in safe mode and running following command but getting syntax error. MySQL version is 8. What is the correct syntax to update password? Or is it happening due to presence of $ and @ in password?

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$kjD q6 MM paSSword@') WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: are you sure those fields Password and User are not case sensitive?

Comment: Direct `mysql.user` table update is errorneous. Use `ALTER USER` statement. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)